# Database unique name and ticker

Tags: python, database, sqlite, database-design

I have created a SQLITE database that has some financial data in it as well as a stock ticker. The database looks like this:
[image]

Since the ticker of a stock (as well as the name) is unique, is it possible to only have the ticker in the database once for each particular company? **Or would I need it to be an entry for each row** (i.e. six entries for this company)

If it is the case I need six entries, is there a way to duplicate this using SQL commands? Since in the CSV file this data gets loaded in, the ticker is only there once, since it is unique.

Eventually I want to be able to do a WHERE clause on the ticker /company name to get the relevant information for that company.

When I run the WHERE clause query I get a KeyError:1

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT SALES, EBITDA FROM financials WHERE Ticker = 'HK001'", cnx)
```

It works fine if I omit the WHERE clause.

```
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS financials')
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE "financials"(
    "Ticker" REAL,
    "Sales" REAL,
    "EBITDA" REAL,
    "index" REAL,
    "year" REAL,
    "Capitalization" REAL,
    "Entreprise Value (EV)" REAL,
    "P/E ratio" REAL,
    "Yield" REAL
)

update financials
set ticker = (
  select f.ticker
  from financials f
  where f.ticker is not null and f.rowid < financials.rowid
  order by f.rowid desc limit 1
)
where ticker is null)
''')
```

I'm not sure where the code from the update financials should go.

Comment: Your query is syntactically correct, so the error does not come from the sql code.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
SELECT SALES, EBITDA FROM financials WHERE Ticker = 'HK001'
```

is correct, but it will return only the row where `Ticker = 'HK001'`.
The best that you can do is update the table by filling the `Ticker` column with the correct value:

```
update financials
set ticker = (
  select f.ticker
  from financials f
  where f.ticker is not null and f.rowid < financials.rowid
  order by f.rowid desc limit 1
)
where ticker is null
```

Comment: The UPDATE code must be executed after you import from the csv file and not after you create the table because then the table is empty and there is nothing to update. Also you will have to read the documentation about cursor.execute() because I'm not sure if you can execute multiple sql statements in one statement.

Comment: Yes it works. Check this simplified demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmnh2nHmokPkNe6aGa5zjD/0